# How to encode a string in python and decode it on a php server

Tags: php, python, encryption, python-requests

I have a python app that communicates with a php server. I am trying to pass an encrypted string from the python app to the php server to be decoded and stored:

**Python Code**

```
url = "http://www.steventaylordevelopment.com/php/rk2.php"
entry = {"username": encode("sdjfkhkj2h34", "username"),
         "mode": "hardcore",
         "score": 121114,
         "attempts": 15,
         "time": 12121,
         "rank": "prince"}
d = {"action": "addEntry",
     "entry": json.dumps(entry)}
r = requests.post(url=url, data=d)
```

encode function:

```
def encode(key, string):
    encoded_chars = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        key_c = key[i % len(key)]
        encoded_c = chr(ord(string[i]) + ord(key_c) % 256)
        encoded_chars.append(encoded_c)
    encoded_string = ''.join(encoded_chars)
    return encoded_string
```

**PHP code**

```
$entry = json_decode($_POST["entry"], true);
$decoded_username = decode("sdjfkhkj2h34", $entry["username"]);
$new_entry = $rk2_db->prepare("INSERT INTO leaderboard (username, mode, score, attempts, time, rank, date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
$new_entry->bind_param("ssiiis", $decoded_username, $entry["mode"], $entry["score"], $entry["attempts"], $entry["time"], $entry["rank"]);
$new_entry->execute();
$new_entry->close();
```

decode function

```
function decode($key, $string){
    $encoded_chars = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
        $key_c = $key[$i % strlen($key)];
        $encoded_c = chr((ord($string[$i]) - ord($key_c) + 256) % 256);
        array_push($encoded_chars, $encoded_c);
    }
    $decoded_string = implode("", $encoded_chars);
    return $decoded_string;
```

I have tested the encode/decode function pairing separately and they function properly, but once i try to pass the encoded string with the http request (using python requests) things go haywire and it doesn't decode the string properly. How can i pass this encrypted string to my php server and then decode it?

**Note**

I am aware this isn't at all secure. That is not of importance as the information isn't sensitive. As a programming exercise I am trying to add a simple layer of obfuscation to the information being passed. I am just trying to figure out why the encrypted string is not being decrypted properly on the server side.

Comment: Is this real code or just for playing around?  If you need to securely transmit data from one place to another you should be using HTTPS/TLS.  This is not even remotely secure, doesn't support UTF-8, isn't authenticated, uses a cipher broken over 50 years ago etc. etc... the list goes on.

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark The information being transmitted isn't sensitive so i am do not particularly care who can end up seeing it or it being super secure. What I am trying to do is to add a simple layer of obfuscation as a programming exercise

Comment: Why not just base64 encode it then? then base64_decode on the php side? Encryption no, but the reality is your solution isn't exactly rocket science to crack. The alternative is to use an encryption library and just hold the key on both servers

Comment: or rot13, but you could just use https, no one in the middle will be able to see a thing

Comment: It doesn't matter if someone cracks it and it doesn't matter who sees it. the information being sent isn't important. I am just trying to figure out  why, in my code setup above, the encrypted string isn't being decrypted properly on the server side. My guess is it has something to do with url encoding and decoding but i can't figure it out.